# Random crash on monomac/Xamarin.Mac

Tags: cocoa, monomac, xamarin.mac

i want to know if any of you have faced an issue that you have a window and you click a few buttons and everything work fine, but then you get this

**2014-07-29 23:08:23.448 Touring[2807:707] -[__NSCFString btnVenue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d0f14b0**

2014-07-29 23:08:23.466 Touring[2807:707] (

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x9a666471 __raiseError + 193
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x976be091 objc_exception_throw + 162
2   CoreFoundation                      0x9a66acb3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x9a5b6522 ___forwarding___ + 1010
4   CoreFoundation                      0x9a5b610e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x976ca2af -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
6   AppKit                              0x90d188a5 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 438
7   AppKit                              0x90d186ad -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 102
8   AppKit                              0x90d67c7b -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 159
9   AppKit                              0x90d82f2a -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2465
10  AppKit                              0x90d82161 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 513
11  AppKit                              0x90d81785 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 690
12  AppKit                              0x90cfda9d -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11953
13  AppKit                              0x90c9991d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4034
14  AppKit                              0x90ade1bc -[NSApplication run] + 823
15  AppKit                              0x90ac6ff8 NSApplicationMain + 1165
16  ???                                 0x030e6948 0x0 + 51276104
17  ???                                 0x030e6768 0x0 + 51275624
18  ???                                 0x00a0e0bc 0x0 + 10543292
19  ???                                 0x00a0e207 0x0 + 10543623
20  Touring                             0x001b5bfc mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 828
21  Touring                             0x00262ebe mono_runtime_invoke + 126
22  Touring                             0x00267328 mono_runtime_exec_main + 376
23  Touring                             0x00267675 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
24  Touring                             0x00114d75 mono_jit_exec + 149
25  Touring                             0x000c57e8 main + 1720
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x94793701 start + 1
```

Any kind of help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok again, after trying a few things without luck, came to my mind to go to the project properties and go to the Mac Build and check the "Use the SGen generational garbage collector" (i don't know if on one of my test i un check this or came like that) but after this, many issues of crashing we're apparentely solved.

Have to try more deep to see if it work 100%.

Any way, thanks to anyone who may read this.